# C# drawstring

Tags: c#, datagrid

Объединил ячейки в datagridview как сделано [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/152113/How-can-i-merge-DataGridView-Rows-Cells-with-Equal) Это один из лучших вариантов, которые нашел в сети. Но.. Есть один баг. При горизонтальном скроллинге текст в объединенных ячейках не скрывается, а перерисовывается.

[image]

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Пока что ясно только то что вы сделали, но не ясно в чем именно проблема (при скроллинге таблицы). Приложите скрины, код и т.п..

Comment: Не разрешает мне пока скрины выкладывать. Так что пока ссылкой

Comment: не уверен, что подойдет, но есть смысл попробовать. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934317/winform-merging-datagridview-headers

Comment: Случай не мой, даже откомпилил тот код, чтобы посмотреть. У него текст сдвигается. В моем случае, текст в объединенных ячейках остается на месте в отличие от обычных ячеек.

Comment: Единственное, чего смог добиться - такую же свалку текста устроить, как в том примере :)